# Caling a Method from a type Members using reflecttion

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, methodinfo

I have a class Person which contains a field for the person's mother and the person's father. I want to call a method called "WriteName" from the members of the person Instance.

How can I do that with reflection?

```
Person child = new Person {name = "Child"} ; // Creating a person
child.father = new Person {name = "Father"}; // Creating a mother for the person
child.mother = new Person { name = "Mother" }; // Creating a father for the person
child.ExecuteReflection();

public class Person
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public Person mother { get; set; }
    public Person father { get; set; }

    public void WriteName()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("My Name is {0}", this.name);
    }

    public void ExecuteReflection()
    {
        // Getting all members from Person that have a method called "WriteName"
        var items = this.GetType().GetMembers(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
                        .Where(t => t.DeclaringType.Equals(typeof(Person)))
                        .Where(p => p.DeclaringType.GetMethod("WriteName") != null);



        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            MethodInfo method = item.DeclaringType.GetMethod("WriteName"); // Getting the method by name
            // Object result = item.Invoke(method); // trying to invoke the method, wont compile
        }


    }
```

I would like to have this output:

```
"My name is mother"
"My Name is father"
```

EDIT:

Th correct code after my changes is:

```
var items = this.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.GetProperty | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
                        .Where(t => t.FieldType.Equals(typeof(Person)))
                        .Where(p => p.FieldType.GetMethod("WriteName") != null);



    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        MethodInfo method = item.DeclaringType.GetMethod("WriteName"); 
        Object result = method.Invoke((Person)item.GetValue(this), null);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have it backwards.  [`Invoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a89hcwhh.aspx) is a method on `MethodInfo`, so you need to call the `Invoke` method on the `method` variable.  It should be:

```
Object result = method.Invoke(item);
```

Comment: how does the Invoke method accept item?

shouldn't the parameter be of type Person?

Comment: @NithinNayagam The first parameter (item) is the instance which is used for the method.

Comment: @ReedCopsey But i get a "Object does not match target type" exception for this code.

Comment: @NithinNayagam The object you pass needs to be the correct type (the type used to get teh MethodInfo)

Comment: @ReedCopsey i am sorry sir, i didn't understand that. Can you please explain it a little more? . Will the OP's required output be obtained by using the above code or should it be changed to suit the program?

Comment: @NithinNayagam I'm still working to try to escape the Unboxing from Object to Person at last line

Comment: @ReedCopsey Do you know how can i do that?

Comment: @WilnerAvila Should you cast it from Object to Person? It works fine for me without the cast.

Comment: @ReedCopsey hm that's true. I was getting error for another reason, before, thanks anyways. It works fine now too

Answer (score 1):

adding to Reed Copsey's answer i dont think you can have item as a parameter to Invoke.

The Invoke method takes in 2 parameters, first the object on which the method should be invoked and second the parameters for the method.

so the 1st parameter should be of type Person (since the method invoked is defined for Person class) and the 2nd parameter should be null (since the method does not take any parameters)

```
Object result=method.Invoke(this,null);
```

i hope the above code will give your required output